# how can i get html output of streamlit webpage?

Tags: python, streamlit

I have developed an application with streamlit. but I couldn't find a solution to get the html of the whole page. How do you think I can find a solution?

I tried to output the texts I created with streamlit as a whole in html. but I couldn't find a solution.
I tried using streamlit html component. however, when I follow a path like this, I cannot print out the entire page. If I could reach the whole page in any way, it would be easy for me to handle the convert operations. but unfortunately I can't access all the items I created in streamlit with a single variable.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import base64
import streamlit as st





a = st.write("asdasd")

export_as_pdf = st.button("Export Report")

def create_download_link(val, filename):
    b64 = base64.b64encode(val)  # val looks like b'...'
    return f'<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,{b64.decode()}" download="{filename}.pdf">Download file</a>'

if export_as_pdf:
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.cell(0,5, a)
    
    html = create_download_link(pdf.output(dest="S").encode("latin-1"), "test")

    st.markdown(html, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Comment: Open the streamlit page in your browser and right click to select "View Page Source" to view the HTML

Comment: you are right, your suggestion is very correct indeed. however, I may need to print out this pdf and send it as an e-mail. So I have to look at it from the automation point of view.

Comment: You may look into using headless browser for this job. I heard that Streamlit has PDF generation in their roadmap for 2023.

Comment: I understand. thank you very much for your help. I will try with selenium.